# JSF2.x: page in sub folder not accessible

Tags: java, jsf-2

This is JSF2.1 , JBoss 6 EAP7.1 server project

I wanted to setup the following:

1. User enters this URL in browser :  http://domain.com/webApp/pathA
2. Server detects the request and notice the /pathA bit
3. JSF redirects browser to
   domain.com/webApp/pathB/b.xhtml

The filter class runs correctly, it is triggered by /pathA and runs response.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/pathB/b.xhtml");

but the browser hits the error:

[address bar] domain.com/webApp/pathB/b.xhtml

An Error Occurred:

/b.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /b.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:232)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:20

If I enter domain.com/webApp/pathB/b.xhtml directly into the browser , I get the same error message

I guess the issue is in web.xml but I cannot see why ...could you please help me?

web.xml

```
    <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>FormFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.kit.filter.FormFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FormFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pathA/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/pathB/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

FormFilter.java

```
package com.kit.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class FormFilter implements Filter{

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        //HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("req.getRequestURI()=" + req.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println("req.getContextPath()=" + req.getContextPath());
        System.out.println("req.getRequestURL()=" + req.getRequestURL());
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

        if (req.getRequestURI().contains("pathA"))
        {
            //HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            //res.sendRedirect("pathA/helloWorldA.xhtml");

            String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath();

            System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ redirect to: " + contextPath + "/pathB/b.xhtml" );

            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "/pathB/b.xhtml");

        }
        else
        {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }


    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    public void destroy() {
    }


}
```

a.xhtml  (b.xhtml is a similar dummy page to a.xhtml)

```
<h:head>
    <title>Secured welcome page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h3>Welcome AAAA</h3>
        <br/>
        <h:outputText value="This is an info page. Everyone has access to it!"/>
        <br/>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

file structure

```
F:.
│  .classpath
│  .project
│  pom.xml
│
├─.settings
│      .jsdtscope
│      org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
│      org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
│      org.eclipse.wst.common.component
│      org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.pref
│      org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
│      org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
│      org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
│
├─src
│  └─main
│      ├─java
│      │  └─com
│      │      └─kit
│      │          ├─controller
│      │          ├─filter
│      │          │      FormFilter.java
│      │          │
│      │          ├─model
│      │          └─util
│      │                  DigitCaptcha.java
│      │                  RequestFormStage.java
│      │
│      ├─resources
│      └─webapp
│          │  helloWorld.xhtml
│          │  index.xhtml
│          │  template.xhtml
│          │
│          ├─pathA
│          │      a.xhtml
│          │
│          ├─pathB
│          │      b.xhtml
│          │
│          └─WEB-INF
│              │  .faces-config.xml.jsfdia
│              │  beans.xml
│              │  faces-config.xml
│              │  web.xml
│              │
│              └─lib
└─target
    ├─classes
    │  └─com
    │      └─kit
    │          ├─filter
    │          │      FormFilter.class
    │          │
    │          └─util
    │                  DigitCaptcha.class
    │                  RequestFormStage.class
    │
    ├─generated-sources
    │  └─annotations
    ├─maven-archiver
    │      pom.properties
    │
    └─webApp
        │  helloWorld.xhtml
        │  index.xhtml
        │  template.xhtml
        │
        ├─META-INF
        ├─pathA
        │      a.xhtml
        │
        ├─pathB
        │      b.xhtml
        │
        └─WEB-INF
            │  .faces-config.xml.jsfdia
            │  beans.xml
            │  faces-config.xml
            │  web.xml
            │
            ├─classes
            │  └─com
            │      └─kit
            │          ├─filter
            │          │      FormFilter.class
            │          │
            │          └─util
            │                  DigitCaptcha.class
            │                  RequestFormStage.class
            │
            └─lib
                    jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
                    primefaces-4.0.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

The   /pathB/* line was causing the issue, the redirection by filter works fine after the line was removed

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```